# Wiresize required for air conditioner of 1.5 tonne is 2.5 sq mm will work?

Tags: wire

My home has copper wire of 2.5 sq mm fitted with 15 Ampere plugs for running appliance. All wires are connected to main electricity meter with max distance (i think it is required) of 40 foots/feets.

The voltage is 220 volt which vary from say 180 to 240 may be. The power consumption stated by AC is 1550 watt (3 star 1.5 tonne voltas AC)

I will be adding a stabilizer 4 KVA to AC and that stabilizer will be inserted in socket of 15 Amperes.

Can you please help will it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2.5mm^2 wire is good for 18A inside a wall, so you are limited by the 15A sockets. A 220V 15A socket can deliver 3.3kW, and even if the voltage drops to 180V it can still do 2.7kW.  Your aircon requires 1.55kW so there is enough power available.

Depending on the type of aircon, it might draw more Volt-Amps than it does Watts. This would happen if it uses a big motor, and has a poor power factor.  Most aircons would be fine, but without looking in the manual for your particular model, it's hard to be sure.

Stabilizers are rarely used in my country, so I can't say much about that part of things, but your 15A sockets cannot supply 4KVA. If the load on the stabiliser stays at 1.5kW, it may be that the stabiliser will always stay below the 2.7kW which is available. If it tries to draw 4KVA from your sockets, there will be problems - either blown fuses, or, if you don't have fuses then a house fire.  Check the manual for the stabiliser to see how it works, and make sure you install 15A fuses somewhere between the wall socket and the stabiliser.

If in doubt, get a qualified electrician in.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Really happy to see my first question on this website answered well.

Answer (score 2):

If the electrical system is properly designed, circuits are generally protected by circuit breakers or fuses at their source.  The circuit breakers or fuses are matched to the wire size used for that circuit;  if the load on the circuit is more than the wires can handle, the circuit breaker or fuse opens the circuit.

Different electrical codes are adopted in different places to standardize the design of these systems.  In the US, the National Electrical Code would allow a circuit fed by a 15 amp breaker or fuse to use 2.5 mm^2 / 14 AWG wire;  that wire can handle that load.  If the standards are similar in your location, your 2.5mm wire is fine for a 15A circuit.

Your air conditioner draws 1550 watts at its rated 220 volts, which translates to about 7 amps.  At a lower voltage, it may draw more current - at 180V, if the power / VA draw is similar, it will draw around 8.6 amps - still well within the circuit's 15 amp max.

Of course if there are other receptacles on the circuit, there may be other loads that could add up and overload the circuit and trip the breaker or blow the fuse - but the air conditioner alone leaves quite a bit of room for other loads on a 15A circuit.

At 240V, if the air conditioner tolerates the higher voltage, it will draw less current.  As long as the insulation, receptacles, breakers, and other components tolerate this slightly higher voltage - which they almost surely do - there won't be a problem with the electrical system.

Voltage stabilizers are rated for the load they can handle.  Since the air conditioner draws only 1550VA and the stablizer is rated for 4000VA, the air conditioner is well within the capacity of the voltage stabilizer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score -1):

Your wire is good enough man, what you need to change is the the 15A socket, just buy a 16 AMP or more Socket and install it on place of old one. No, issues.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I don't think you can just increase the size of an outlet a bit; you'll end up with a different kind of socket.

Comment: @AgentMahone - Even if you could do that, it would not be safe;  installing a bigger receptacle without upgrading the wiring and breaker doesn't add any capacity, really just makes it easier to overload the circuit.